# GitHub action branch creation for code review pull request

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to create a GitHub workflow that will run ONLY when a new branch is created with a pattern.  The purpose of this is to create a Code Review Pull Request when a new branch is pushed to origin, but only on the first time the branch is created, so using a `push` event will not work and why I'm looking at `create`.

All of these combinations fail where any new branch created will run, instead of those just matching the pattern

```
name: "Create Code Review PR"

on: 
  create:
    branches: ['feature/**']
```

or

```
name: "Create Code Reivew PR"

on:
  create:
    branches:
      - 'feature/**'
      - 'support/**'
      - 'hotfix/**'
```

In both of these scenarios, if push a new branch called `no-code-review`, the above workflow will still run, but my expected behavior is that it wont run, but it should when a new branch such as these: `feature/new-branch`, `support/new-support-branch` or `hotfix/fix-this` ONLY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The create event does not support a branch filter.

The alternative would be using an if condition on your step or job:

```
if: ${{ contains(github.ref, 'refs/heads/releases/') }}
```

Here's more information: https://github.community/t/trigger-job-on-branch-created/16878/5